# Function that returns the sum of the product of a list plus one

Tags: python, enumerate

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

Write a function called enum_sum which takes a list of numbers and returns the sum of the numbers multiplied by their corresponding index incremented by one.

Ex: enum_sum([2, 4, 6]) -> (index 0 + 1)*2 + (index 1 + 1)*4 + (index 2 + 1)*6 -> 1*2 + 2*4 + 3*6 -> 28

OK. That's what I have so far:

```py
    def enum_sum(lst):
        res = 0
        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
            res += 1 + num*idx 
        return res

    print(enum_sum([2, 4, 6]))
```

I get the following error AssertionError: 11 != 14

Any clue what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Programming language?

Answer (score 0):

```
def enum_sum(lst):
    res = 0
    for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
        idx += 1  # To increase index by 1 first before multiplying
        res = idx * num
    return res


print(enum_sum([2, 4, 6]))
```

output>> 18

I'm not quite sure what you want but with the code does all the operations separately and returns only the new value of the last number in the list which is 18. If you want to return all the new values of the numbers in the list you have to create a list to append those new values eg.

```
def enum_sum(lst):
        res = []
        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
            idx += 1  # To increase index by 1 first before multiplying
            new_values = idx * num
            res.append(new_values)
        return res
        
    
 print(enum_sum([2, 4, 6]))
```

output >> [2, 8, 18]

Answer (score 0):

You want to multiply [the value] by [the index plus one]. What you are doing is multiplying [the value] by [the index] and then adding [one].

So your code should look like this, instead.

```py
def enum_sum(lst):
    res = 0
    for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
        res += num * (idx + 1)
    return res

print(enum_sum([2, 4, 6]))
```

BONUS: One-liner version:

```py
def enum_sum(lst):
    return sum(x * (i + 1) for i, x in enumerate(lst))
```